# Tracker recursive indexing fails

Tags: 14.04, gnome, home-directory, tracker, indexing

I would like tracker to index my complete home directory and all sub-directories / files.
I set my home directory as the only directory in the tracker "places" (for indexing) in the tracker configuration and turned on recursive indexing but unfortunately it seems to have no effect.
When I start Activities (Ubuntu Gnome 14.04) via the super key I just can reach all files/direcotories that are directly in my home directory, all sub-directories or files are not indexed and not reachable by the Activities view :(.

How can I fix that? Any ideas?

Comment: **UPDATE**: If I search via the GUI of tracker the index seems to be ok, all folders and files are found. Just the _Activities_ overview (super key) does not use this index :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug with gnome-shell, but has been fixed in 15.04. You can use tracker-search or tracker-needle instead in the mean time.